# How to find this element using Selenium (python)

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, testing

How to locate this element?

[image]

```
<div _ngcontent-ysj-c5>
    <div _ngcontent-ysj-c5 class="list-items unselected"> == $0
        <!---->
        " Installation "
    </div>
</div>
```

i have tried

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(text(),' Installation ')]").
```

&

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()=' Installation ']").click();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: you should give more information about the path

Comment: include your code in your question, I've tried to do this but it is currently being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(.,'Installation')]")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[.=' Installation ']")
```

=)

Comment: @jaop Helpful answer but why dropping the _tagName_ `<div>` from the locator?

Comment: it can be div instead of *, to locate div element that has value '  Installation '. In case we use *, all elements that have value '  Installation ' will match. in this case, the first matching element will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try below locators:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[text()='Installation']")
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Installation']")
```

Comment: @Shrini You were almost there, there is a syntax error in the _xpath_, an additional `)` after _Installation'_

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for that I just corrected it. It was a typo.